# Git workflow/actions and svn checkout

Tags: github, svn, github-actions

For some weired reason I need to checkout using svn in github actions. I tried following

```
name: My Build from SVN

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: ghcr.io/XXXXX/XXXXX:main

    steps:
      - run : |
          svn version
          svn co --username ${{ secrets.SVN_USER }} --password ${{ secrets.SVN_PASSWORD }} --no-auth-cache <URL>
```

But I am getting following error each time

Username: svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ''
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge ()
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.